# How to use checklistbox in angularjs or in bootstrap

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

Can anyone suggest me how can I display a checkbox list in angularjs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="app">
    <div ng-controller="TodoCtrl">
        <span ng-repeat="(checkboxName, checkboxValue) in checkboxes">
            {{ checkboxName }}
            <input type="checkbox" ng-model="checkboxValue"/>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.controller('TodoCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.checkboxes = {
        'foo': true,
        'bar': false,
        'baz': true,
        'baa': true
    }
});
```

---

**Update:**

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="app">
    <div ng-controller="TodoCtrl">
        <!--<span ng-repeat="(checkboxName, checkboxValue) in checkboxes">
            {{ checkboxName }}
            <input type="checkbox" ng-model="checkboxValue"/>
        </span>-->
        <checklist checkboxes="checkboxes" on-change="checkboxInfo(name, value)"></checklist>
    </div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.controller('TodoCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.foo = true;
    $scope.bar = false;
    $scope.baz = true;
    $scope.baa = true;

    $scope.checkboxes = {
        'foo': $scope.foo,
        'bar': $scope.bar,
        'baz': $scope.baz,
        'baa': $scope.baa
    };

    // Non-encapsulated activity: updates parent scope values
    $scope.checkboxInfo = function(name, value) {
        console.log('Checkbox "' + name + '" clicked. It is now: ' + value + '.');
        $scope[name] = value;
    };

    // This shouldn't do anything if we delete '$scope[name] = value', since we isolated the scope:
    $scope.$watchCollection('[foo, bar, baz, baa]', function() {
        console.log($scope.foo, $scope.bar, $scope.baz, $scope.baa);
    });
})
.directive('checklist', function($timeout) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: { 
            checkboxes: '=',  // create an isolate scope w/ 2-way binding
            onChange: '&'     // execute a function in the parent scope
        },
        template: 
            '<span ng-repeat="(checkboxName, checkboxValue) in checkboxes">' +
                '{{ checkboxName }}' +
                '<input type="checkbox" ng-model="checkboxValue" ng-change="onChange({name:checkboxName, value:checkboxValue})"/>' +
            '</span>',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            // Add encapsulated activity as necessary
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: Hi gyeh,This worked for me but Iam unable to select or deselect the check boxes. Is there any other option apart from true or false because true is not allowing me to deselect and false is never allowing me to select.

Comment: You could do all of that by changing my original code slightly. Just change `<input type="checkbox" ng-model="checkboxValue"/>` to `<input type="checkbox" ng-model="checkboxValue" ng-change="update(checkboxName, checkboxValue)"/>` and create a function like this in the controller: `$scope.update = function(name, value) { $scope[name] = value; }`. But I think it's better to create a directive. See my updated post for that!

Comment: If you want to change the checkbox value, you can use angular's directive attributes `ng-true-value` and `ng-false-value`: https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.26/docs/api/ng/input/input%5Bcheckbox%5D